# Check box in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

My GUI has two checkboxes, namely `colourcheck` and `Texturecheck`, below a single search button. If I click on the search button, it should check for both types mentioned above and respective program should run, also if both box are in 'MIN' position i.e., not checked it should give a message to user stating `select type of search`.

I've clipped search_callback program.

```
function Search_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Search (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data


% --- Executes on button press in colourcheck.
function colourcheck_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to colourcheck (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data

% Hint: get(hObject,'Value') returns toggle state of colourcheck
if (get(hObject,'Value') == get(hObject,'Max'))
    Search_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
else
   % Checkbox is not checked-take approriate action
end
```

However I am not able to meet the requirements. Please help me, any solution is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

From the description in your question, you don't want `Search_Callback` called when you click `colourcheck_Callback`.  Instead you want some other action taken when the search button is clicked based on which check boxes are selected. You could use a callback like the following for your search button:

```
% --- Executes on button press in search.
function search_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to search (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

isTexture = get(handles.Texturecheck,'Value');
isColour = get(handles.colourCheck,'Value');
if and(isTexture, isColour)
    'do something'
elseif isColour
    'do something else'
elseif isTexture
    'do something else'
else
    'warn user'
end
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But what to write in colourcheck & Texturecheck_callback functoins?

Comment: You don't need to write anything in the colourcheck and texturecheck callbacks. You read in their value in with get(handles.Texturecheck,'Value') and get(handles.colourCheck,'Value'). If you like the answer, consider accepting it! :)